# R: Counting Tuples in Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I hope the title is wide but clear enough. Any hint, help very appreciated.

I do have a Dataframe in R, given by three columns and around 70k rows. I have to do the following:

Assuming, I identify the first two columns of a row with a tuple (x,y) and the column z as a 'key' which is associated to the tuple (x,y), I want to count how often the given tuple (x,y) is associated to z - whereas (x,y) could be associated to more than one key z. So, although this is the first step in analyzing the map (x,y) -> z, I think it would be convenient to have a dataframe giving me how often (x,y) is associated to z.

For example:

Adam, Germany, Accounting

Bert, Austria, Operations

Bert, Germany, HR

Adam, Germany, HR

And I would like to see:

HR -> Bert, Germany;
      Adam, Germany

Operations -> Bert, Austria

Accounting -> Adam, Germany

Comment: Could you edit the question by pasting the output: `dput(head(df, 20))` where `df` is the data frame in question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ill have to come up with a way to change the data without its 'structure' as its work related and I can not post that here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok how about this.

```
require(data.table)

# your data
dt1 <- data.table(name = c("Adam", "Bert","Bert", "Adam"),
                 cntry = c("Germany",  "Austria","Germany","Germany"),
                 occ = c("Accounting","Operations","HR", "HR"))


# make table
dt2 <- dcast(dt1, cntry + name ~ occ,value.var = "occ", fun.aggregate = length)

# make grand total
dt2[ , Total := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = colnames(dt2)[-(1:2)]  ]


# output
     cntry name Accounting HR Operations Total
1: Austria Bert          0  0          1     1
2: Germany Adam          1  1          0     2
3: Germany Bert          0  1          0     1
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt <- data.frame(name = c("Adam", "Bert","Bert", "Adam"),   
+ cntry = c("Germany",  "Austria","Germany","Germany"),  
+ occ = c("Accounting","Operations","HR", "HR"))  
dt$tuple<-paste(dt$name,",",dt$cntry,sep="")  
dt$tuple1<-dt$tuple  
dt<-reshape(dt[,3:5],idvar="occ",timevar="tuple1",direction="wide")  
dt[is.na(dt)]<-""  
dt<-data.frame(occ=dt[,1],tuples=apply(dt[,-1],1,paste,collapse="|"))  
dt$tuples<-gsub("\\|+","|",dt$tuples)  
dt
```

## output

```
  occ                    tuples  
1 Accounting             Adam,Germany|  
2 Operations            |Bert,Austria|  
3 HR               Adam,Germany|Bert,Germany
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to continue working with the data so the other answer is convenient, but I'll use yours for a presentation.